# Push errors on solo repository

Tags: git, github, rstudio, github-pages, quarto

I have a github repository for my personal website that I am editing using RStudio and Quarto. When I first set it up it was pushing commits fine, but now whenever I try to push I always get the same error:

```
 ! [rejected]        HEAD -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://pagelocation'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Note that I work on this repository on my own so it's not coming from someone else updating it, also I have tried all manner of `git pull origin main`, manually fixing the errors and adding them, fetch, hard reset and when I pull it says everything is ok. However, when I push again it just continuously gives me these errors whenever I try to push an edit. I can force the push and it works, but this seems like bad form. It just seems like it's not recognizing the local repository or something.

Comment: Are you working on this repository from 2 different computers? Or do you have two separate local copies of the repository for quarto and rstudio?

Comment: Or are you editing the files in the repository on the GitHub website?

Comment: No its all on one computer and there is only one local copy and I'm editing the files on Rstudio then hitting the commit and push button in rstudio

Comment: And what are you doing with quarto (sorry, I don't know what this software is)?

Comment: quarto is basically just a static site generator that makes the files for the website after i edit it in R markdown, so the files that are pushed are made from quarto

Comment: So if you make changes, commit and try to push them, you get errors, then you fix the errors, then you push again which succeeds, and if you then make more changes and commit and try to push them, you get the same errors again?

Comment: right, if i pull and push after fixing, it says everything is ok and up to date, but then if i make an edit and push it, it gives me the above error

Comment: I'll add that if i force it it works, but again i feel like its not best practice but i dont know